# Java Splitting Strings with several conditions

Tags: java, string, split

I want to split a string along several different conditions -
I understand there is a Java String method called String.split(element), which splits the String into an array based on the element specified.

However, splitting among more objects seems to be very complex -- especially if the split must occur to a range of elements.

**Precisely, I want java to split the string**

- "a>=b" into {"a",">=","b"}
- "a>b" into {"a", ">", "b"}
- "a==b" into {"a","==","b"}

I have been fiddling around with regex too just to see how to split it exactly based on this parameters, but the closest I've gotten is just splitting along a single character.

EDIT: a and b are arbitrary Strings that can be of any length. I simply want to split along the different kinds of comparators ">",">=","==";

For example, a could be "Apple" and b could be "Orange".

So in the end I want the String from "Apple>=Orange" into 
{"Apple", ">=", "Orange"}

Comment: What are the conditions for the split?

Comment: The conditions I specified are under what I want precisely.

Comment: Why not rewrite your strings as a >= b, a < b and then split on " "?

Comment: You haven't specified any conditions, you just included some sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: I am taking in an input that could both have whitespace and not have whitespace - in my case, I already considered the cases with whitespace

Comment: Leave a space between each group of tokens you want to split double space oper space double equal space answer split on space.

Comment: that's not going to work with split since splitting around some character will not include it in the array returned

Comment: Your sample can easily be solved by `if (input.equals("a>=b")) return new String[] {"a",">=","b"};` etc. But obviously that's not what you want, right? Because it doesn't address the underlying logic, which you haven't specified.

Comment: Are the elements before and after the comparator operaton single-digit, or can they be arbitrary length?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify my logic. I want to compare two int variables together in java, without calling upon them directly. All I want for this layer is to split the string into an array so I can easily access these variables in seperated form later on

Comment: For a more generic solution, you can try something like `input.split("\\b")`.

Comment: use regex to group the none white space problems and use split to do the white space problems

Comment: The elements before and after the comparator are arbitrary - so I cannot just seperate based on length

Comment: from your samples, i can see the rule is to have the first alphabet set and the last alphabet set and whatever in between. is it correct ?

Comment: Sedrick Jefferson the regex portion is the precise part that I need help with - I do not know how to split based on both 2 character elements and one character elements at the same time.

Comment: try this : (\d+.\d*)\s*([>,=,<]+)\s*(\d+.\d*) Here: https://www.regex101.com/r/HBsst1/1  Add your test cases.

Comment: Do you HAVE to use String.split() ??? My suggestion is use String.toCharArray() instead and then iterate that array until you find the symbols you mentioned and build a new String.

Comment: by the way what result do you expect from "hello>=hi>=no" ? is it `{"hello>=hi",">=","no"}` or `{"hello",">=","hi>=no"}` or `{"hello",">=","hi",">=","no"}` or ... :)

Comment: What exactly are valid comparison operations, just the three mentioned or more? What exactly are valid operand inputs? Integers, decimal numbers (in which notations), words, letters? Edit: Sorry, overlooked your edit, so valid operands are clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions. No matter if you use a, or b or abc for your variables you'll get the first variable in the group 1, the condition in the group 2 and the second variable in the group 3.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)([<=>]+)(\\w+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("var1>=ar2b");

    if(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    }
```

Comment: Perfect. How does regex know the difference between >= and >, however? I've been trying to learn it for days and still don't understand how it identifies ">" differently from ">="

Comment: your regex will capture much more than what's intended

Comment: I prefer this regex instead : `"(\\w+)"+(compop)+"(\\w+)"` where `compop=">|<|==|<=|>="`

Comment: @KevinHu while this answer works, pay attention that it captures much more than what you want example : "hello>>no" will still match and you'll get `{"hello",">>","no"}`

Comment: Yes, it's better to limit the options, if you are only using >, <, ==, <= and >= it's better to use this regex "(\\w+)(>|<|==|<=|>=)(\\w+)"

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for your examples:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList("a<=b".split("\\b")));
```

It splits the string on word boundaries.

If you need more elaborate splitting, you have to provide more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could code it out by hand and use whichever tokens you want to split on like so

```
public String[] splitString(String word)
{
    String[] pieces;
    String[] tokens = {"==", ">=", "<=","<", ">"};
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
    {
        if(word.contains(tokens[i]))
        {
            pieces = {
                    word.substring(0, word.indexOf(tokens[i])), 
                    tokens[i], 
                    word.substring(word.indexOf(tokens[i]) + 
                      tokens[i].length(), word.length())};
            return pieces;
        }
    }
    return pieces;
}
```

This will return an array with whatever is before the token found, the token itself and whatever is left.

Comment: `a` ?!! don't you mean `word` ?